# "Execution Failed" error In Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When I'm running app in Xamarin Studio I got an error "Execution Failed"
How to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We're going to need more information to help you solve this. Is this a fresh installation of Xamarin Studio? Does this happen only with your own app, or also with demo apps? Please [edit] this information into the question. If it only happens with your own app, please give us a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your emulator, please try close the emulator and re-run your project. The problem occurs sometimes when you use your emulator for so long in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I was trying to share my experience. I met the same problem, and it was resolved by trying the above. Thank you.